# Magento show multiple products with different product images in product list

Tags: list, magento, collections, colors, product

I have an unusual request from a client as follows:-

The customer has selected a specific colour (by layered nav) however this colour is NOT the colour assigned to the configurable option. An example here. Customer picks red but this could be red, dark red or burgandy. I would then need to show 3 copies of this product with the correct colour selected to show for the media portion of the list object.

I have extended the Product_list block and added a function called getColourProductCollection() which is an extension of the _getProductCollection() function. the attributes are filter_colour (the one shown on the layered nav (primary colour) and the configurable attribute is called config_colour (secondary / real colour).

I realise this is going to be a fair amount of work but this is a feature my client is insisting on moving forward. The code i have is working and my extended function is being called (and is currently returning the normal collection). I could build this with an object by looping over all products finding the children and adding any which have the correct primary colour attribute. my question however is how to return this as a collection as is the case with the getLoadedProductCollection() function call? Handling the image swapping code is already pretty much implemented provided i have a collection returned to fit in with existing list template.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or pointers here.

p.s. i found this page http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-convert-an-array-to-a-collection-object-in-magento/ which would allow me to create and add each item. Would this be a good way to proceed here?

p.p.s. After looking further into adding manually (the above p.s.) i realise that the moment i add the same product again it wont add it to the collection.

Comment: Perhaps i can use simple products and add this way but how then would i deal with this on the list page when the associated products are not shown in catalogue? Am i even in the right area with this?

Comment: Resolved by using a collection of all products with this atttribute